# How to create the correct formatting for T(n) time complexity notation of two outcomes.

Tags: amsmath, matrices, algorithms

How can i create the following notation from Introduction to Algorithms, Cormen, et al, i've been trying the following, but the Omega is indented and the \textnormal is quite sketchy in my opinion, is there a better way of doing this?

This is what i have:

```
\begin{equation}
T(n) = \left\{
\begin{matrix} 
\Omega(k + n) & \textnormal{if } k > 0 \\
\Omega(1) & \textnormal{if } k = 0
\end{matrix}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

This is what i want:
[image]

Comment: Welcome between the users of TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `cases` environment and simply `\text`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
T(n) = \begin{cases} 
\Omega(k + n) & \text{if } k > 0 \\
\Omega(1)     & \text{if } k = 0
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You trumped me by one minute :-( I'm deleting my answer away with due care and vote positive your question. My English is bad.